# Joomla 4 user login programmatically

Tags: authentication, joomla, joomla4

In the Joomla 3x, I have this code to login an user, it worked well.

```
$options = array();
$credentials = array();

$credentials['username'] = $username;
$credentials['password'] = $password;

$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login($credentials, $options);        
$result = ($result) ? 1 : 0;

echo json_encode( array('loggedIn' => $result) );
jexit();
```

But in the Joomla 4.2 it says error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmaoU.png)

How to solve it? thanks!

Comment: Please post all of your Joomla content on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- a Stack Exchange specifically designed to collect all Joomla Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code, it's worked with Joomla 4.

```
$options = array();
$credentials = array();

$credentials['username'] = $username;
$credentials['password'] = $password;

$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();
$container->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
$result = $app->login($credentials, $options);      
$result = ($result) ? 1 : 0;

echo json_encode( array('loggedIn' => $result) );
jexit();
```

Comment: Code is working properly, Do you have any idea how to set up cookies after login?